# How to prevent that the TextViews Content goes over the edge

Tags: android, listview, textview, word-wrap

I have a simple ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/overvieList"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and this layout for the ListView items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/overviewItemImage"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:rowCount="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/overviewItemHeader"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/overviewItemCategory"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/overviewItemText"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </GridLayout>

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i use a modified ArrayAdapter to fill the ListView.

ok that works.

But how can I prevent it that the TextViews Content (on the right) goes over the edge??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set layout_marginRight in textview . i hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

just add a little margin `android:layout_marginRight="5dp"` to your TextViews